# What is the last hook triggered before an order is created in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to validate the content of a cart before allowing the order to be placed. This seems to be a trivial task using common hooks like `woocommerce_checkout_process` action hook, which works fine in most of the cases.

In the website I am working on, it seems there is some complex cases where other plugins are editing the content of the cart thus the above hook isn't enough.

I want to know what is the last hook called before the order is created in the database and before any payment is done. I want to make sure I run my validation after any potential changes to avoid non-needed orders.

I have looked around here: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html searching with the keyword `order` but there is a ton of results.

I have identified (I guess) [the `create()` function](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-abstract-wc-order-item-type-data-store.html#source-view.43) which contain the hook `woocommerce_new_order_item` but this one is called after the creation not before.

Which hook will make sure there is no changes done between my validation and the creation of orders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last hook before order creation is [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order` located in  `WC_Checkout` method `create_order()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L386) As you can see the order is created just after this hook with the code line:

```
$order->save();
```

For order items *(the following hooks are also located in [`WC_Checkout` method `create_order()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L386), before order creation)*:

- "line" items use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` filter hook.
- "fee" items use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_fee_item`  filter hook.
- "shipping" items use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_shipping_item`  filter hook.
- "tax" items use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_tax_item`  filter hook.
- "coupon" items use `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_coupon_item`  filter hook.

Now **for fields validation**, you can use 2 different hooks located in [`WC_Checkout` class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.8.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php):

- `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` ([some examples with this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20user%3A3730754%20woocommerce_after_checkout_validation))
- `woocommerce_checkout_process` ([some examples with this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20user%3A3730754%20woocommerce_checkout_process))

Comment: `create_order()` is done after the paiement? or the paiement is done somewhere in the middle? I want to avoid order creation and also make sure the paiement is not done too

Comment: NO it's done before payment, see that in `WC_Checkout` `process_checkout()` method where the method `create_order()` is called at the beginning before payment.

Comment: ok thanks, will try that hook and see if it's fixes my issue